# C Programming undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to compile following code using gcc (tdm-1) 4.7.1 with notepad, and command prompt on windows 10. previously add bin folder path to global variables,but when i try to compile i get following error " undefined reference to `WinMain@16'".However same code works fine with codeblocks!.

PS: I compile it like this "cd /d path of code then gcc filename.c"

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    printf("Hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us how exactly (with what commands) you compile this code in the terminal.

Comment: It's not your program that's wrong, it's something in the build process. WinMain@16 is referring to the "real" entry point of a windows exe. In a console application this is provided by C-runtime library. The first thing I would look at is that you are telling your compiler to build a console app. Google for the "--subsystem" option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found What was wrong accidentally.After writing my code through notepad,I forgot to save file ctrl+s so i just trying to compile empty file.

Answer (score 3):

This is strange.

```
gcc --version
```

> gcc.exe (tdm64-1) 5.1.0
>      Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>      This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>      warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE

Without any options I get

```
gcc filename.c
a.exe
```

> Hello world

Notice however

```
gcc -municode filename.c
```

Generates a linker error

> `D:/bin-win64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_w.o)`: In function `wmain`:
>   `C:/crossdev/src/mingw-w64-v4-git/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_w.c:23`: undefined reference to `wWinMain`
>   `collect2.exe`: error: `ld` returned 1 exit status

The startup function in MinGW is `mainCRTStartup`, which calls main. If there is no user specified `main`, the runtime provides one for you, that one calls `WinMain`.

So your app should compile from the command line as well.

Comment: I know this , but may problem from windows 10.I tried this many times on windows 7 .However  when I run gcc --version it works fine .

Comment: I had a similar problem - if you use `-municode` and `#define _UNICODE` then you have to use `wmain` instead of `main` in mingw.